# Extending imagestore models

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps, django-inheritance

I'm trying to install imagestore app in my project. Default models are created succefully, and all other parts working properly.

But, it have a feature to extend base (abstract) models and create your own by some complicated mechanism. This is mine model:

```
from django.db import models 
from imagestore.models.bases.album import BaseAlbum 
class Newalbum(BaseAlbum): 
    title = models.CharField("title", max_length=128) 
    class Meta(BaseAlbum.Meta): 
        app_label = "imagestore" 
        abstract = False
```

Also I have a string `IMAGESTORE_ALBUM_MODEL = 'art.models.Newalbum'` in my settings.
When I run syncdb it tells me Backend module "art.models" does not define a "Newalbum" class. ('module' object has no attribute 'Newalbum').
But of course it defined.

And the strangeness is only begins. When I put debug statement in the place where imagestore trying to get my model it prints proper module (already imported) and proper class name (string). But! `dir(mod)` prints only variables appeared before "from imagestore.models.bases.album import BaseAlbum" .In above example only "models" and default underscored attributes. Why? What I don't know about importing modules?

I already tried to install it in many awkward combinations of settings properties, versions of django (and required apps), app_label and so on. It creates tables, when I  doesn't add IMAGESTORE_ALBUM_MODEL in my settings, but this models hasn't any BaseClass' behaviour.
So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose your Newalbum class it's inside art (folder) >> models .py (file), right? You also need to have an _____init_____.py inside art's folder in order to be considering it as a package.

Comment: Nope, art/__init__.py is created automatically by manage.py startapp. I thing problem is inside imagestore's models/base/__init__.py or base/album.py, because it's execute my models.py properly just before i trying `from imagestore.models.bases.album import BaseAlbum`.

Comment: ...oh sorry. There must be "backend module art.models", not just "backend module art".

Comment: Yes, you have the models.py inside art's folder with Newalbum class write in that same models.py?

Comment: nope, that's how its supposed to be. Means I don't what's wrong too.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. No solution yet.

Comment: There are better docs here: https://github.com/m000/imagestore/blob/54494e46c1b8f546cac4b9168fac6d1c9732b85d/docs/extending.rst that didn't make it to Read The Docs. I've followed them, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! While stepping through the import process (I added the following to imagestore.utils.load_class)

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

I found that there is a circular import. Here's the order of things (slightly simplified):

1. load_class(IMAGESTORE_ALBUM_MODEL)
2. from imagestore.models.bases.album import BaseAlbum
3. BaseAlbum has an FK to IMAGESTORE_IMAGE_MODEL (head), so it gets imported with load_class
4. load_class(IMAGESTORE_IMAGE_MODEL)
5. from imagestore.models.bases.image import BaseImage
6. BaseImage has an FK to IMAGESTORE_ALBUM_MODEL (album), so it gets imported with load_class
7. When this calls __import__ IMAGESTORE_ALBUM_MODEL is already in sys.modules, though incomplete because it's still being built. And thus the module doesn't have an "Album" attribute yet.

The quick solution is to move the head field to models.album.Album and remove it from BaseAlbum. After doing this I was able to get the site running again. You must use the models package in your new app (not a simple models.py), with Image and Album in separate files.

If this isn't clear enough, drop me a line and I'll try to do better.

Comment: Yes, this is some kind of right answer. I'm already done it too. At now, I should drop a line to imagestore's maintainers, or fork it on github with this additions to models and documentaion. This is strange, why it encountered only now, and why no one noticed about it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure anyone trying to extend both classes would run into this. I've already opened an issue in the hovel repo.

Comment: From Kristijan Mitrovic (still not enough rep to comment) :How did you manage to do this (replacing `title` field in `BaseImage` while doing it within the same app `app_label = "imagestore"` stated in the question, or mentioned `head` field from `BaseAlbum` stated in the answer)?

According to the Django docs on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted it is not permitted to do that. I'm getting *django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'title' in class 'CustomImage' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'BaseImage'*

Comment: You should probably ask that as a new question. The issue resolved here was circular imports when both Album and Image have been overridden.